# pyshool Private Test Cases failed

Tags: python

I was solving [this](http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s1-q13) question. I wrote this code but it gives out an error "Private Test Cases failed." Here is my code. Take a look and tell me what's wrong, please.

```
def dec2hex(num): 
    a = str(num)
    if (a[-1]=='0'):
        return "0x0%x"%num
    else :
        return "0x%x"%num
```

Here is the question:
"Write a function that does a decimal to hexadecimal conversion.
Hint: Make use of "%x" for hexadecimal format."

Comment: If you can, post the question on here.

Comment: Why type of type of inputs are you throwing inside of it? Also is there any particular reason that you're checking if the last digit is a 0? As far as I know of that check shouldn't affect anything. Realistically you could probably just return "0x%x" % num.

Comment: check this i also tried that http://i.imgur.com/69J4Nj9.png @Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true your code will pass the known test cases, it appears to fail on "Private Test Cases". Notably, your code outputs `0x014` when passed a value of 20. It is probably just wanting the return to be at least 2 hex digits long, plus the '0x'.

In this thinking, instead of checking if the last given digit is a zero, check the length of the resulting hexadecimal conversion. This should be enough to get you on the right track.

I don't want to post the final code (using this thinking, I was able to get the tests to pass), because that would almost amount to cheating. Do note that your code is fine, it's just the given requirements are lacking.